# Query with WHERE based on Combo Box value: Index off by 1

Tags: sql, ms-access

This should be simple, but I can't figure out the issue or find an answer:

I have a table `Units` with the relevant fields `UnitName` and `Division`.

I'm querying:

```
SELECT UnitName
FROM Units
WHERE Division = '9';
```

As simple as it gets. The record's `Division` field in the table is populated by lookup/combobox with RowSource query:

```
SELECT Division.ID, Division.Abbreviation
FROM Divisions
ORDER BY Abbreviation;
```

The bound column is 0.

Yet the first query, selecting a UnitName, only works when the `WHERE Division = 'X'` is set so X is one less than the actual ID I can see in the table.
E.g., if I look in my test table, I have a record with the Division field showing 9, the query only finds this record if I set X = 8. This works consistently with any number of dummy records I create.

Why?!

Comment: The "bound column" comment is probably a hint that you are running into trouble in the user interface. Have you tried running this as a raw query? presumably it works there. If that is the case focus your attention on the dropdown or other ui element you are interacting with.

Comment: Set BoundColumn to 1 and ColumnCount to 2, and ColumnWidths to 0";1.0"

Comment: Do **not** use lookups in your table: [ The Evils of Lookup Fields in Tables](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The bound column is 0.

That's your issue. If you want the `.Value` of the Combo Box to be the `Division.ID` of the selected item then the Bound Column should be 1, not 0. If the Bound Column is 0 then the Combo Box `.Value` will be the zero-based index of the item as it appears in the drop-down list. The fact that this appears to manifest itself as an off-by-one error is just a coincidence.